# For loop in C is looping more times than it should. Why?

Tags: c, debugging

Here's the offending code:

```
int i, y, total = 0;

printf("%d\n", i);

for (i=0;i<2;i++) {
    printf("why\n");
}
```

And the function it's included in:

```
void getStats(int month, const struct DailyData yearData[], int sz, struct MonthlyStatistic* monthly){

    // based off monthly stats, function finds min and max temp (float), average temp and the total precipitation

    int i, y, total = 0;

    printf("%d\n", i);

    for (i=0;i<2;i++) {
        printf("why\n");
        //printf("\n%d %d %d ", yearData[i].month, yearData[i].day, yearData[i].year);
        //draw(symbolToDraw(yearData[i].condition, aver),20);

    }

    float max = 0, min = 0, averaged = 0, prec = 0;

    //counts number of days in month

    for (y = 0; y < 366; y++) {
        if (yearData[y].month == month) {
            total++;
        }
    }

    //loop through year, assign data to variables if given row's month matches int month parameter

    for (i=1;i<=365;i++) {
        if (yearData[i].month == month) {
            if (yearData[i].high > max) {
                max = yearData[i].high;
            }
            if (yearData[i].low < min) {
                min = yearData[i].low;
            }
            //printf("high: %f, low: %f\n", yearData[i].high, yearData[i].low);
            averaged = average(yearData[i].high, yearData[i].low);
            prec += yearData[i].precipitation;

        }
    }


    monthly[month].averageTemperature = averaged;
    monthly[month].maxTemperature = max;
    monthly[month].minTemperature = min;
    monthly[month].totalPrecipitation = prec;

    return;

}
```

This code seems normal to me, however when I incorportate that loop in that function it has the following output:

[image: wtf]

From the look of things, when the loop exits the compiler goes backwards (if that's even possible?) and goes through the loop PLUS the print statement before it for a definate amount of times. How on earth could this sort of thing even happen? Is there something obvious I'm missing here or is this bug a lot more devious?

Comment: The best way to debug something like this is to try to create a minimal counter example -- remove any code not necessary to reproduce the offending behavior. On stackoverflow, questions about debugging some code in which you didn't produce a minimal verifiable example are considered off-topic.

Comment: Where and how is `getStats` called? If that is called in a loop then the output would make sense. Also, `printf("%d\n", i);` that is printing an uninitialized value (not that it should have bearing on the question).

Comment: in C, indexing into an array is in the range 0...(array size -1), please adjust your `for()` statements to correctly index into the array(s).  this 'oops' is particularly noticeable in the line: `for (i=1;i<=365;i++) {`

Comment: the variables `max` and `min` are not initialized correctly.  Suggest: `max = INT_MIN;` and `min = INT_MAX;`

Comment: the variable `averaged` is being (re)calculated every day of the year, rather than for the whole year.  so the setting of `monthly[month].averageTemperature = averaged;` is only showing the value for the last day of the year.  However, what (I think) is really wanted is the average over the year,  so daily, accumulate the high sum and the low sum.  After the year is over, calculate avg high as high sum /365 and calculate avg low as low sum /365 to calculate year avg as (avg high+avg low) / 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, based on your question *title*, your question is why `why` is being printed more than twice, that's easy. The `for` loop *is* only running twice in the code you've posted, as evidenced by the fact it prints an integer between each set in your output.

Since that integer is likely to be the the printing of (the uninitialised) `i` variable, the most likely explanation is that you're calling `getStats()` more than once (probably in a loop).

---

However, based on your comment:

> From the look of things, when the loop exits the compiler goes backwards (if that's even possible?) and goes through the loop PLUS the print statement before it for a definite amount of times.

it may be that your question is why it seems to be printing it in reverse order (two `why` lines then the number).

That's an artefact of your scrollback buffer in the window. Were you to have an extra line in the buffer, you would no doubt see another integer above the line you currently understand to be the first. I'd suggest looking at the *end* of the output and you'll no doubt see two `why` rather than an integer.